# Exception caught by rendering library using GNav

Tags: flutter, exception

For my Bottom Navigation bar i'm using google's nav bar. I added another button to the bar and then I saw the following error:

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.6 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Row Row:file:///Users/mustafa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_nav_bar-5.0.6/lib/src/gnav.dart:94:16

To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
http://127.0.0.1:9102/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A58843%2F6Lb7ghFx7BY%3D%2F&inspectorRef=
inspector-0

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#7761c relayoutBoundary=up4 OVERFLOWING:
needs compositing
creator: Row ← ColoredBox ← Container ← GNav ← Padding ← ColoredBox ← Container ← MyBottomNavBar ←
MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.bottomNavigationBar>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
_ActionsScope ← ⋯
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(w=361.0, 0.0<=h<=812.0)
size: Size(361.0, 56.0)
direction: horizontal
mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
mainAxisSize: max
crossAxisAlignment: center
textDirection: ltr
verticalDirection: down

The code I have written for my bottom bar is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
class MyBottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  void Function(int)? onTabChange;
  MyBottomNavBar({super.key, required this.onTabChange});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 20),
      child: GNav(
        color: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        gap: 8,
        onTabChange: (value) => onTabChange!(value),
        tabs: const [
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.home,
            text: 'Home',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.payment_sharp,
            text: 'Payment',
            ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.monetization_on_sharp,
            text: 'Transactions',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.person,
            text: 'Profile',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.settings,
            text: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```